# No Action in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Below is my code

```
 <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp2", [])
            app.controller("ShowController", ['$scope', function ($http) {
                $scope.Get = function () {
                    var adata = { EmpId: 'EmpId' };
                    var JSon = JSON.stringify(adata);
                    EmpId = $("#EmpIdb").val();

                    $http({
                        method: "Get",
                        url: servUrl + "Show",
                        data: JSon,
                    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                        alert(response.data);
                    }, function myError(error) {
                        alert(response.statusText);
                    });
                }
            }])
        </script>
    </title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="ShowController">
    <center>
        <h3> Please Enter Your Emp Id</h3></br>
        <input type ="text" id="EmpIdb" /></br>
        <input type="button" id ="Fetch" value="Fetch Details" ng-click="Get();"/>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </center>
```

which is not working.
There is no error in the console and I am not able to debug it either.
Any help welcomed

Comment: `app.controller("ShowController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($http, $scope) {` And no need to add ; semicolon in ng-click

Comment: @Rakeschand the true one is: `app.controller("ShowController", ['$scope', '$http', function ( $scope, $http) {`

Comment: semicolon does impact...ve to put service as $scope do ..

Comment: None of his works.

Comment: check function get called???

Comment: No, it is not being called

Comment: What errors you are getting in console

Comment: I doubt in this code - EmpId = $("#EmpIdb").val();    Might be it should be adata.EmpId = $("#EmpIdb").val(); and also app.controller("ShowController", ['$scope', function ($http) { . It should be app.controller("ShowController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

Comment: I am getting no errors in console.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems. But I do not really get why error is not coming

1 . Where is the `servUrl` coming from?

2 .

```
            $http({
                method: "Get",
                url: servUrl + "Show",
                data: JSon,
            })
```

to

```
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: servUrl + "Show",
                data: JSon,
            })
```

3 . Change this in 3rd line

```
app.controller("ShowController", ['$scope', function ($http) {
```

to

```
app.controller("ShowController", ['$scope', '$http', function ( $scope, $http) {
```

Fix these. then try again.

**EDITED**

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fegkr9GWNcJpZTJXHwPg) Plunker with working code.

Comment: Hi ,
I have set the srvUrl to some value .

Comment: Changed Get to GET
and the 3rd line too.
Still not working

Comment: Then you have to inject the value too.

Comment: But in this condition still the code is not working? I don't get it. Can you make a plunker of you code So I can debug

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/QNQZ4KBZPnaJ0RPDZ84W?p=catalogue

I guess this is what you have asked for.

Comment: Yes. Your question answer is in there. Angular is working with all its component you just have to put your specific URL for your `GET` request.

Comment: Probably, there is an issue with "ng-click" directive.

Comment: Nothing is happening on the button click. No navigation.

Comment: `ng-click` is working perfectly fine. On the button click the `http` `get` request is made and hello world is displayed. There is no navigation.

Comment: i meant it is not hitting the service url. it is not working even when i try an alert

Comment: You have to put your service url in the `servUrl` variable.

Comment: i did that.. no response 
same goes with just an alert msg too.

Comment: So this is not my answer's wrong but Its your `URL` that is not working. Here in this plunker `http` request is working fine and alert is being shown.

Comment: Okay Okay..
Dont get offensive.i did not mean that your code was wrong. Just not working with me

Comment: No. I'm not getting offensive just trying to help you. Now if you are satisfied as it is the answer to your question you should mark it correct. :)

Comment: You know what. from your responses and dumb questions I'm pretty sure you are new to coding and does not know any thing about angular or even coding. No one can help you like this. You should learn to code first and get its basic knowledge. :)

Comment: Yeah.. i am new to coding and sorry for the dumb questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below. You are not passing scope in controller function.

```
 <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp2", [])
        app.controller("ShowController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.Get = function () {
                var adata = { EmpId: 'EmpId' };
                var JSon = JSON.stringify(adata);
                EmpId = $("#EmpIdb").val();

                $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: servUrl + "Show",
                    data: JSon,
                }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                    alert(response.data);
                }, function myError(error) {
                    alert(response.statusText);
                });
            }
        }])
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. just inject $scope and $http in your controller

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp2", [])
    app.controller("ShowController", ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
        $scope.Get = function () {
            var adata = { EmpId: 'EmpId' };
            var JSon = JSON.stringify(adata);
            EmpId = $("#EmpIdb").val();

            $http({
                method: "Get",
                url: servUrl + "Show",
                data: JSon,
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                alert(response.data);
            }, function myError(error) {
                alert(response.statusText);
            });
        }
    }])
```